# Link inside a button doesnt work on any browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

I would to create a link inside a button.  I understand that a normal HTML link button works with all other browsers except for internet explorer.  I added some javascript, but now the link isn't working in browser.  My javascript skills are not good at all as I am still learning.

```
<tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear and Reset" />
        <input type="button" value="Return To Term" onClick="javascript:location.href = commute.php?clickedletter=<?php echo $clickedterm ;?>;" /></td>
```

Comment: can you also provide the working version code?
so that we can analyze the difference between working and not working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to enclose the string in single quotes:

```
<input type="button" value="Return To Term" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'commute.php?clickedletter=<?php echo $clickedterm ;?>';" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the URL inside quotes:

```
<input type="button" value="Return To Term" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'commute.php?clickedletter=<?php echo $clickedterm ;?>'" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="location.replace('commute.php?clickedletter=< ?php echo $clickedterm;?>'" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear and Reset" />
    <input type="button" value="Return To Term" onClick="javascript:location.href='commute.php?clickedletter=<?php echo $clickedterm ;?>';" /></td>
```

you must use quotes.